# Swift: Undeclared type TCPClient

Tags: swift, tcp

I'm working with SwifSockets : https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket : After following directions on how to use it, I found this code on stack overflow: [Sending Message Over TCP in Swift (NULL terminated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873306/sending-message-over-tcp-in-swift-null-terminated/36878275#36878275)

```
let client:TCPClient = TCPClient(addr: "127.0.0.1", port: 8080)
var (success,errmsg)=client.connect(timeout: 1)
    if success{
        var (success, errmsg) = client.send(data:Array<UInt8>("|~\0".utf8))
        if success{
            let data=client.read(1024*10)
            if let d=data{
                if let str=String(bytes: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
                    print(str)
                }
            }
        }else{
            print(errmsg)
        }
    }else{
        print(errmsg)
    }
```

All I need is to send an Uint8 array over a tcp connection. I think the code I found will do that but I'm getting "Use of undeclared type 'TCPClient' " on the first line of code. I'm wondering what protocol I'm missing, or what should import to make the above error go away and have the code working.

Besides this I also tested CocoaAsyncSocket but I can't send the byte array over tcp because I can't encode it properly.

Comment: did you import it?

Comment: Yes sir, I dragged ysocket.c and ysocket.swift to my project just like the manual says. As far as using the import keyword nothing works, no combination of ysocket or import SiwftSocket will have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag the folder 'ysocket' into your project,
and remember to choose 'Create groups' in 'Added folders'

Answer (score 0):

Need to import `SwiftSocket`,
To import `SwiftSocket` module use the following code:

```
import SwiftSocket
```